# cakephp session does not work on shared host (godaddy, ICDsoft)

Tags: session, cakephp, shared, host

I have an application developed using Cakephp. The session works fine on local host too. I see the session can be set, and read out in localhost, I can also see the session file created as sesssion_save_path defined in php.ini.

First, I wrote a small session check php file to test the shared host, i am 100% sure the shared host has no issue on session.

However, the session seems not working on shared host. I can set a session, I can see the session file created on the host too, but when I refresh it, and do :
    $this->Session->read("User.id");
    $this->Session->check("User.id");

There is nothing.

What should i do? Does it has something todo with the cakephp cache?

Answer (score 3):

First we want to mention that we are not CakePHP experts, so we might be unable to provide the best possible answer.

We tested sessions in CakePHP 2.2 on our shared hosting environment, with the following sample script/controller:

```
 public function index() {//The default action for a CakePHP controller
    CakeSession::start();

    echo 'Hello world.<hr/>';

    // test that the session actually works
    $counter = 0;
    if ( $this->Session->check('counter') ) {
      $counter = $this->Session->read('counter');
    } else {
      echo 'Creating session' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    ++$counter;

    $this->Session->write('counter', $counter);

    echo "You were here {$counter} time(s)\n\n";
    var_dump($this->Session->read('counter'));
  }
```

It seems that the session data was saved and read properly. If you still have an issue with a CakePHP installation on a server of ICDSoft, we would advise you to contact our support team. We might not be always able to provide proper debugging support, but we are always willing to try.

Best regards,

ICDSoft Team

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at the CakePHP cookie being assigned to your browser to see whether the session ID keeps changing. If it does then your session is not being persisted.

Secondly it might be worth checking whether the `$_SESSION` superglobal is usable also.